# Why does S3.deleteObject not fail when the specified key doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, aws-sdk

Using the [AWS SDK for Node](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html), why do I not get an error when trying to delete an object that doesn't exist (i.e. the S3 key is wrong)?

If I specify a non-existent bucket on the other hand, an error is produced.

If you consider the following Node program, the `Key` parameter lists a key which doesn't exist in the bucket, yet the `error` argument to the callback is `null`:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk')

function getSetting(name) {
  var value = process.env[name]
  if (value == null) {
    throw new Error('You must set the environment variable ' + name)
  }
  return value
}

var s3Client = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: getSetting('AWSACCESSKEYID'),
  secretAccessKey: getSetting('AWSSECRETACCESSKEY'),
  region: getSetting('AWSREGION'),
  params: {
    Bucket: getSetting('S3BUCKET'),
  },
})
picturePath = 'nothing/here'
s3Client.deleteObject({
  Key: picturePath,
}, function (err, data) {
  console.log('Delete object callback:', err)
})
```

Comment: Because that's what the specs says it should do -> *"Removes the null version (if there is one) of an object and inserts a delete marker, which becomes the latest version of the object. If there isn't a null version, Amazon S3 does not remove any objects."*, if the object doesn't exists, it's still not an error when calling `deleteObject`

Comment: @adeneo Mind writing this as an answer?

Comment: so how do I know if it failed or succeeded?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because that's what the [**specs**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) say it should do.

> **deleteObject(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request**
>
> Removes the null version (if there is one) of an object and inserts a
>   delete marker, which becomes the latest version of the object. If
>   there isn't a null version, Amazon S3 does not remove any objects.

So if the object doesn't exist, it's still not an error when calling `deleteObject`, and if versioning is enabled, it adds a delete marker even though there was nothing to delete previously.

Comment: A correction — if the object does not exist, a delete marker is not added.

Comment: @JoelL That is incorrect. If the object does not exist a deletion marker is still added.

Comment: @AubtinSamai This applies only for Buckets with versioning enabled, right?

Comment: @yerzhan7 That is correct. The delete-marker is only used when versioning is enabled, otherwise when not enabled the object is simply deleted.

Comment: As a side note, this kind of behaviour is called _idempotent_: instead of "this request should delete this object", you can think of it as "this request should make sure this object does not exist (anymore)". If the object did not exist already, then that contract is still respected.

Comment: so how do I know if it failed or succeeded?

Comment: If it responds with status code in the 2xx, then you know it succeeded @BiswasKhayargoli. But I don't think there is anyway to know if there was actually anything deleted.. which does seem bizarre.