# Files aren't deleted from Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm using aws-sdk in nodejs, this is the part of the code that delete the files:

```
 var s3_params = {
         Bucket: util.getEnvVar('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
         Delete: {Objects: [{Key: document.bucket_path }]}
  };

s3.deleteObjects(s3_params, function (err, data) {

                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.send(data);
                }
            });
```

The response that return from amazon look fine, but when i look on the bucket inside the s3 interface the file still exist.

also try to use "deleteObject" method with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks good. Are you sure you are passing a Key of a file that exists? Beware that if you try to delete a Key that does not exist, AWS won't throw an error, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697746/why-does-s3-deleteobject-not-fail-when-the-specified-key-doesnt-exist).

Comment: Well after i create a debug route with all the object keys i found my problem, i pass incorrect key, thanks :)